# How to get RC connection signal And Camera HD signal with DJI Mobile SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, dji-sdk

I am making an iOS app with DJI SDK-3.5.1(objective-c). I have problems getting RC signal and HD signal as shown in the pic below. Does anyone know in which class and methord can I get the information?

[image]

Comment: Add more information for jump into your problem.

Comment: I need to show the RC connection signal and camera HD signal in my app based on DJI SDK 3.5.1 vision.But I can't find the related class and method.Do u have any idea?Thx for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answers.

In [`DJIAirLinkDelegate`](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/AirLink/DJIAirLink.html#djiairlink_protocol_inline) protocol

- Downlink method: `airLink:didUpdateDownlinkSignalQuality`
- Uplink method: `airLink:didUpdateUplinkSignalQuality`

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the 4x version I would suggest http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/VideoSignalWidget.html#videosignalwidget_videosignalstrength_inline

found from
http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/VideoSignalWidget.html#videosignalwidget_videosignalstrength_inline

Comment: Thx for your reply.But the API you mentioned is for DJI UI widget.I need to get the signal strength in Mobile SDK so I can display my own icons accordingly.Do u have any idea about it?Thx again.